# Why does python return the n+1th list element rather than the nth?

Tags: python, python-3.x

i m new to Python and have following problem

```
>>> choice = [1,0,1,1,]
>>> choice = [1,0,1,1]
>>> print(choice)
[1, 0, 1, 1]
>>> print(choice[2])
1
```

why it print 1 rather than 0?

Comment: Because Python uses **zero**-based indexing. `choice[1]` would print `0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python uses something that is called **zero based indexing**, which means that the first element in a list is referred to element number **0** and not **1**.

Answer (score 5):

It prints 1 because list indices start from zero and not from one. Thus:

```
choice[0] is  1
choice[1] is  0
choice[2] is  1
choice[3] is  1
```

Answer (score 2):

Because of the way math works, Python starts its lists at 0 rather than 1. It seems weird, but there are many [advantages](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex34.html) to this, even though it is mostly arbitrary.